# How to type cast an void pointer to array pointer in c?

Tags: c, pointers

**The dynamically allocated functions malloc,calloc,realloc in the stdlib library returns the void pointer

I want to convert the void pointer retuned to an array pointer is it possible to do so **

```
void* x=malloc(6*sizeof(int));
int (*ptr)[3];
```

*Can we typecast x and assign it to ptr ?*

Comment: void pointers can be cast to any other pointer type. So `ptr = x;` should be fine.

Comment: ... That is, void pointers can be converted *implicitly*, by assignment, to any other object pointer type.  They may also be converted *explicitly* via a cast.  So "yes" and "yes".  The allocation functions wouldn't be much use if you couldn't use them to get pointers of the required types.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  x points to an array of 6 ints, and ptr is a pointer to an array of 3 ints.

Answer (score 1):

You can implicitly convert `x` to `ptr` via the assignment:

```
int (*ptr)[3] = x;
```

or use an explicit cast:

```
int (*ptr)[3] = (int (*)[3]) x;
```

As `x` is a pointer to array of 6 ints, I am not sure why you want a pointer to the first 3 of these.  `gcc -Wall -Wextra ...` doesn't even generate a warning for out of bound access `printf("%d\n", (*ptr)[4]);` so why use a a plain `int *ptr`?

```
int *ptr = malloc(6 * sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'normal' way to do this is

```
int *ptr = malloc(6*sizeof(int));
```

or maybe

```
int *ptr = malloc(3*sizeof(int));
```

since you dont seem to know if you want 3 or 6 ints

Comment: The OP might want to allocate a 2D array 2x3, in which case `int (*ptr)[3] = malloc(2*3*sizeof(int));` is perfectly fine and correct, unlike `int*` which would be wrong in that case.

Answer (score 0):

1D array of 6 `int`:

```
int* arr = malloc(6 * sizeof *arr);
...
arr[i] = something;
...
free(arr);
```

2D array of 2x3 `int`:

```
int (*arr)[3] = malloc( sizeof(int[2][3]) );
...
arr[i][j] = something;
...
free(arr);
```

In either case there is no need of a `void*` as a middle step.